# Quantum Gates on Density Matrices

Tags: quantum-information, density-operator

Let's say we have some general mixed state

$$\Big(\begin{matrix}
\alpha & \beta \\
\beta^\dagger & \delta\end{matrix}\Big)$$

Purely a mechanical question, how might I apply, say, a NOT operator to this state? I've read a few papers - e.g. [Quantum Circuits with Mixed States](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/9806029.pdf) - that purport the answer the question, but they immediately dive into the mathematics of superoperators without ever giving an actual, practical example.

By representing the $n\times n$ mixed state with an $2n\times 1$ vector, I've derived that we get reasonable-looking answers by using $O\otimes O$, i.e. the Kronecker product of a quantum gate $O$ with itself, but "reasonable-looking answers" isn't even in the same ballpark as a rigorous mathematical derivation so I'd like to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think one way of deducing the action of operators on mixed states is by considering first pure states. Let's say, we have a pure state $|\psi\rangle$ and the  result of acting with an operator $A$ is another vector $|\psi'\rangle$, i.e.
\begin{equation}
A |\psi \rangle = |\psi'\rangle \, .
\end{equation}
The density operators corresponding to the original and final states are then related by
\begin{equation}
\rho' = | \psi' \rangle \langle \psi' | = A | \psi \rangle \langle \psi | A^{\dagger} = A \rho A^{\dagger} \, .
\end{equation}
We can be even more formal and consider the spectral decomposition of a general state $\rho = \sum_n p_n | \phi_n \rangle \langle \phi_n |$ and follow the same reasoning, that is, apply $A$ to each $|\phi_n\rangle$, and deduce that indeed $\rho' = A \rho A^{\dagger}$ in general.